# replace domainName with folder path using java

Tags: java

I am trying to replace apache image path to linux ubuntu folder path while retrieving file path from DB.

```
http://test.mydomain.com/MainFolder/subFolder/image1.jpg
```

should be

```
/var/www/MainFolder/subFolder/image1.jpg
```

here MainFolder is static folder. so how can i replace "http://test.mydomain.com/" to "/var/www/" where before MainFolder/

Comment: Look at `String#replaceAll` and some basic regex tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get domain part of url and replace that part of string like below way..

```
String imageURL = "http://test.mydomain.com/MainFolder/subFolder/image1.jpg"; 

String domainPart = getDomainPart(imageURL);

String folderPath = imageURL.replace(domainPart, "/var/www");


public String getDomainPart(String url) {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String hostname = uri.getHost();

    String domainPart = scheme + "://" + hostname;

    return domainPart;
}
```